# How to insert custom inline javascript code in php phalcon framework

Tags: phalcon

I want to insert from Controller in the end of some view's code like this

```
"<"script> setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);"<"/script>
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's multiple ways to do this in PhalconPHP. Depending on your needs, you might be able to get away with just:

```
$js='setInterval(function(){alert("Hello");},3000);';
$this->view->js=$js;
```

then from the view, you'd do:

`<script><?php echo $js; ?></script>`

If you need to insert the JavaScript into your **top-level** `index.phtml` from a nested view, the way to accomplish this is to first edit your `ControllerBase.php` and define a new collection:
`$this->assets->collection('footer');`

Then add a reference to the `footer` collection from your top-level index.phtml file:

```
<body>
    <?php echo $this->getContent(); ?>
    <?php $this->assets->outputJs('footer'); ?>
</body>
```

You could also use `output('footer')` instead if you just wanted a dynamic place in the document you can insert HTML of any kind.  Note that a collection specializes in managing CSS and JavaScript, hence the outputJS method, but can also handle miscellaneous code for other purposes. There's also `outputCSS`, `outputInlineJs`, `outputInlineCss`, `outputInline`, and simply `output`.  See:
http://php-phalcon-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Assets_Manager.html

Then edit your `ControllerBase.php` to initialize the asset to an empty collection:
`$this->assets->collection('footer');`
*(if you skip this step, your code will see errors if your top-level index.phtml file tries to output the contents of a non-existent collection if you never write to it, so always initialize it to an empty collection so it exists.)*

Finally, from the controller you want to use, you'd do:
`$this->assets->collection('footer')->addInlineJs($js);`
where `$js` is your inline JavaScript, excluding the script tags.
You can also work with external JavaScript files by using
`->addJs(...)`.  By default it will be relative to your application directory, inserting a `/` automatically. If you dislike this functionality, you can set the second parameter to `false` then it will allow you to specify your own leading `/` or point your resources at another domain.
As far as the assets you can add to a collection, see:
https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Assets_Collection.html

Note that you can also add assets to your collection from your view and the changes would still appear in your top-most `index.phtml`.

It is also worth noting that you don't need to actually use collections, you can simply use assets without a collection, but I think collections are more powerful in that you get to name them so there's another level of separation in case you need to manage more than one kind of collection of data.

In terms of what you're trying to accomplish, if you're just trying to give the user a message, this is what Phalcon's `flash` is for, not to be confused with Adobe Flash which is for playing videos. Phalcon's `flash` is for flashing messages to the user such as error messages, or your form submit successfully kind of messages. See:
https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/flash.html

If you're still confused what flash is, a demo of what it's output is, you can see in the screenshot here: https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/_images/invo-2.png
That is output of `->error(...)` and `->notice(...)` respectively. The flash component keeps track of a collection of the messages you'd like to show the user. Then once you're ready to display them to the user you'd call:
`<?php echo $this->flash->output(); ?>` from your view. It is best to make this call from your top-most template or a template which is always included in your top-most template such as your navigation template so you can easily display messages to the user. It is also useful for debugging. I'd suggest using twitter bootstrap for styling the flash output.

Some sample applications which you might find useful:
https://github.com/phalcon/invo
https://github.com/phalcon/vokuro
https://github.com/phalcon/website
https://github.com/phalcon/forum

Further reading:
https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Thank you very much.All you wrote works. You were very helpful to me
Phalcon is excellent Framework